# do yield in for loop within sequence computation expression

Tags: f#, sequence

Why these work

```
let x = seq { for i in 1 .. 10 do yield i }
let x = seq { for i in 1 .. 10 -> i }
let x = seq { for i = 1 to 10 do yield i }
```

but this one doesn't?

```
let x = seq { for i = 1 to 10 -> i }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [the F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997064), sequence expression can be either normal computation expression (this is the case where you write `do yield`) or it can be a short form that is specific to sequence expressions:

```
seq { comp-expr }
seq { short-comp-expr }
```

The `comp-expr` case covers your first and last working examples. The short form uses `->` and the specification explicitly says that the only allowed short form is with the `in` keyword:

```
short-comp-expr :=
   for pat in expr-or-range-expr -> expr        -- yield result
```

There are many other short forms that would be useful in practice, but I guess that the aim is to provide a special syntax just for this one, very frequent, case and otherwise keep the language uniform.

Comment: The link to the spec no longer works, anyone can look at the [lastest spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), section `6.3.11 Sequence Expression`.

Answer (score 4):

To add some more details to @Tomas's answer, your first and third example are elaborated as:

```
let x = Seq.collect (fun i -> {yield i}) {1..10}
```

while your second example is translated to:

```
let x = Seq.map (fun i -> i) {1..10}
```

Translation rules are mentioned in [Section 6.3.11 in the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997064). In that section, you can also see that F# treats full `for` loops (`for...in...do` and `for...to...do`) uniformly, but the special syntax with `->` is applied to `for...in...` block only.

There is no problem since you can always use `for...in...` to express `for...to...`.